# R plotly crashing on linux machines with no X11

Tags: r, ggplot2, x11, plotly

I'm ploting together a `plotly` `heatmap` along with `ggplot2` dendrograms I processed a bit (incompatible with `heatmaply`), on a `linux` machine without `X11` and running into an error:

Here's the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(dendextend)

#dendogram data
set.seed(1)
my.mat <- matrix(rnorm(10*100),nrow=100,ncol=10,dimnames = list(paste("g",1:100,sep=""),paste("s",1:10,sep="")))
my.hover.mat <- matrix(paste(paste(rownames(my.mat),paste("description",1:100,sep=" "),sep=":"),colnames(my.mat),signif(my.mat,3),sep="'</br>'"),nrow=100,ncol=10)
x <- as.matrix(scale(my.mat))
dd.col <- as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(x)))
dd.row <- as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(t(x))))

#cut dd.col 
dd.col <- cut(dd.col,h=6)$upper
ggdend.col <- as.ggdend(dd.col)
leaf.heights <- dplyr::filter(ggdend.col$nodes,!is.na(leaf))$height
leaf.seqments.idx <- which(ggdend.col$segments$yend %in% leaf.heights)
ggdend.col$segments$yend[leaf.seqments.idx] <- max(ggdend.col$segments$yend[leaf.seqments.idx])
ggdend.col$segments$col[leaf.seqments.idx] <- "black"
ggdend.col$labels$label <- 1:nrow(ggdend.col$labels)

ggdend.col$labels$y <- max(ggdend.col$segments$yend[leaf.seqments.idx])
ggdend.col$labels$x <- ggdend.col$segments$x[leaf.seqments.idx]
ggdend.col$labels$col <- "black"
ggdend.col$segments$lwd <- 0.5

ggdend.row <- dendro_data(dd.row)
ggdend.row$labels$label <- ""
ggdend.row$labels$col <- "black"
ggdend.row$segments$lwd <- 0.5

#ggplot dendrograms
py <- ggplot()+geom_segment(data=ggdend.col$segments,aes(x=x,y=y,xend=xend,yend=yend))+coord_flip()+annotate("text",size=4,hjust=1,x=ggdend.col$label$x,y=ggdend.col$label$y,label=ggdend.col$label$label,colour=ggdend.col$label$col)+labs(x="",y="")+
  theme_minimal()+theme(axis.text=element_blank(),axis.ticks=element_blank(),panel.grid=element_blank())
px <- ggplot()+geom_segment(data=ggdend.row$segments,aes(x=x,y=y,xend=xend,yend=yend))+annotate("text",size=4,hjust=1,x=ggdend.row$label$x,y=ggdend.row$label$y,label=ggdend.row$label$label,colour=ggdend.row$label$col)+labs(x="",y="")+
  labs(x="",y="")+theme_minimal()+theme(axis.text=element_blank(),axis.ticks=element_blank(),panel.grid=element_blank())

# heatmap
col.ord <- order.dendrogram(dd.col)
row.ord <- order.dendrogram(dd.row)
my.mat <- my.mat[col.ord,row.ord]
my.hover.mat <- my.hover.mat[col.ord,row.ord]
heatmap.plotly <- plot_ly() %>% add_heatmap(z=~my.mat,x=factor(colnames(my.mat),lev=colnames(my.mat)),y=factor(rownames(my.mat),lev=rownames(my.mat)),hoverinfo='text',text=my.hover.mat)

# plotting it all together
eaxis <- list(showticklabels = FALSE,showgrid = FALSE,zeroline = FALSE)
p_empty <- plot_ly(filename="r-docs/dendrogram") %>% layout(margin = list(l = 200),xaxis = eaxis,yaxis = eaxis)
all.together <- plotly::subplot(px, p_empty, heatmap.plotly, py, nrows = 2, margin = 0.01)
```

which gives:
[image]

On a `linux` machine with no `X11`, however, the conversion of a `ggplot2` object to a `plotly` object, that takes place in the `plotly::subplot` command, crashes with this error message:

```
Error in .External2(C_X11, paste("png::", filename, sep = ""), g$width,  :
  unable to start device PNG
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhKg7.png
```

The same error is obtained if I try to convert the dendrogram `ggplot` objects: `px` and `py`, to `plotly` objects:

```
> plotly_build(py)
Error in .External2(C_X11, paste("png::", filename, sep = ""), g$width,  :
  unable to start device PNG
```

So that is not a solution to my problem.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a workaround to the `X11` problem? I won't be able to install `X11` on my machine so that one is not a possible solution.
2. Perhaps there's a way to generate a `plotly` `dendrogram`, either directly or from a `dendrogram` or `ggdend` objects - i.e. without having to convert a `ggplot2` to a `plotly` object.